# Improving neo4j cypher query performance

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

Hi I'm running a cypher query that appends nodes to graph, the cypher is very big and this affected the performance, currently the query takes 3780 ms, is there anything I can do to make it faster? 
(I couldn't put the whole query due to the size limit)

```
MERGE (pisrael:country {_id:'israel'})
MERGE (pisrael)-[:Has]->(pyafo:city {_id:'yafo'})
MERGE (pyafo)-[:Has]->(yafo_pavon:region {_id:'avon'})
MERGE (yafo_pavon)-[:Has]->(yafo_avon_pbotsfordforest:street {_id:'botsfordforest'})
MERGE (pisrael)-[:Has]->(phaifa:city {_id:'haifa'})
MERGE (phaifa)-[:Has]->(haifa_pcambridgeshire:region {_id:'cambridgeshire'})
MERGE (haifa_pcambridgeshire)-[:Has]->(haifa_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie:street {_id:'ferryprairie'})
MERGE (phaifa)-[:Has]->(haifa_pbedfordshire:region {_id:'bedfordshire'})
MERGE (haifa_pbedfordshire)-[:Has]->(haifa_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest:street {_id:'botsfordforest'})
MERGE (pyafo)-[:Has]->(yafo_pbedfordshire:region {_id:'bedfordshire'})
MERGE (yafo_pbedfordshire)-[:Has]->(yafo_bedfordshire_pferryprairie:street {_id:'ferryprairie'})
MERGE (phaifa)-[:Has]->(haifa_pberkshire:region {_id:'berkshire'})
MERGE (haifa_pberkshire)-[:Has]->(haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest:street {_id:'botsfordforest'})
MERGE (haifa_pberkshire)-[:Has]->(haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp:street {_id:'goodwinramp'})
MERGE (pyafo)-[:Has]->(yafo_pberkshire:region {_id:'berkshire'})
MERGE (yafo_pberkshire)-[:Has]->(yafo_berkshire_pbotsfordforest:street {_id:'botsfordforest'})
MERGE (phaifa)-[:Has]->(haifa_pavon:region {_id:'avon'})
MERGE (haifa_pavon)-[:Has]->(haifa_avon_pbotsfordforest:street {_id:'botsfordforest'})
MERGE (pyafo)-[:Has]->(yafo_pcambridgeshire:region {_id:'cambridgeshire'})
MERGE (yafo_pcambridgeshire)-[:Has]->(yafo_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest:street {_id:'botsfordforest'})
MERGE (yafo_pbedfordshire)-[:Has]->(yafo_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp:street {_id:'goodwinramp'})
MERGE (yafo_pcambridgeshire)-[:Has]->(yafo_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie:street {_id:'ferryprairie'})
MERGE (yafo_pberkshire)-[:Has]->(yafo_berkshire_psmithamcauseway:street {_id:'smithamcauseway'})
MERGE (yafo_pcambridgeshire)-[:Has]->(yafo_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp:street {_id:'goodwinramp'})
MERGE (haifa_pberkshire)-[:Has]->(haifa_berkshire_psmithamcauseway:street {_id:'smithamcauseway'})
MERGE (haifa_pbedfordshire)-[:Has]->(haifa_bedfordshire_pferryprairie:street {_id:'ferryprairie'})
MERGE (yafo_pbedfordshire)-[:Has]->(yafo_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest:street {_id:'botsfordforest'})
MERGE (haifa_pavon)-[:Has]->(haifa_avon_pferryprairie:street {_id:'ferryprairie'})
MERGE (yafo_pavon)-[:Has]->(yafo_avon_psmithamcauseway:street {_id:'smithamcauseway'})
MERGE (yafo_pberkshire)-[:Has]->(yafo_berkshire_pferryprairie:street {_id:'ferryprairie'})
MERGE (haifa_pcambridgeshire)-[:Has]->(haifa_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest:street {_id:'botsfordforest'})
MERGE (haifa_pberkshire)-[:Has]->(haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie:street {_id:'ferryprairie'})
MERGE (haifa_pavon)-[:Has]->(haifa_avon_pgoodwinramp:street {_id:'goodwinramp'})
MERGE (yafo_pbedfordshire)-[:Has]->(yafo_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway:street {_id:'smithamcauseway'})
MERGE (yafo_pavon)-[:Has]->(yafo_avon_pferryprairie:street {_id:'ferryprairie'})
MERGE (yafo_pberkshire)-[:Has]->(yafo_berkshire_pgoodwinramp:street {_id:'goodwinramp'})
MERGE (yafo_pavon)-[:Has]->(yafo_avon_pgoodwinramp:street {_id:'goodwinramp'})
MERGE (haifa_pavon)-[:Has]->(haifa_avon_psmithamcauseway:street {_id:'smithamcauseway'})
MERGE (haifa_pcambridgeshire)-[:Has]->(haifa_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp:street {_id:'goodwinramp'})
MERGE (haifa_pbedfordshire)-[:Has]->(haifa_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway:street {_id:'smithamcauseway'})
MERGE (yafo_pcambridgeshire)-[:Has]->(yafo_cambridgeshire_psmithamcauseway:street {_id:'smithamcauseway'})
MERGE (haifa_pbedfordshire)-[:Has]->(haifa_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp:street {_id:'goodwinramp'})
WITH yafo_avon_pbotsfordforest, haifa_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, haifa_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_avon_pbotsfordforest, yafo_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_avon_psmithamcauseway, yafo_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_avon_pgoodwinramp, yafo_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_avon_pgoodwinramp, haifa_avon_psmithamcauseway, haifa_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp
MATCH (haifa_avon_pbotsfordforest)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_avon_botsfordforest_C1:circle {_id:1})
CREATE (haifa_avon_botsfordforest_C1)-[:postRel]->(haifa_avon_botsfordforest_1_P1:post {_id:1})
SET haifa_avon_botsfordforest_C1.post_count=1


WITH yafo_avon_pbotsfordforest, haifa_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, haifa_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_avon_psmithamcauseway, yafo_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_avon_pgoodwinramp, yafo_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_avon_pgoodwinramp, haifa_avon_psmithamcauseway, haifa_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp
CREATE (haifa_avon_pferryprairie)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_avon_ferryprairie_C8:circle {_id:8})
CREATE (haifa_avon_pferryprairie)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_avon_ferryprairie_C9:circle {_id:9})
SET haifa_avon_pferryprairie.circle_count=9
with yafo_avon_pbotsfordforest, haifa_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, haifa_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_avon_psmithamcauseway, yafo_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_avon_pgoodwinramp, yafo_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_avon_pgoodwinramp, haifa_avon_psmithamcauseway, haifa_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp
MATCH (haifa_avon_pferryprairie)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_avon_ferryprairie_C6:circle {_id:6})
CREATE (haifa_avon_ferryprairie_C6)-[:postRel]->(haifa_avon_ferryprairie_6_P1:post {_id:1})
SET haifa_avon_ferryprairie_C6.post_count=1
with yafo_avon_pbotsfordforest, haifa_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, haifa_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_avon_psmithamcauseway, yafo_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_avon_pgoodwinramp, yafo_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_avon_pgoodwinramp, haifa_avon_psmithamcauseway, haifa_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp
MATCH (haifa_avon_pferryprairie)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_avon_ferryprairie_C5:circle {_id:5})
CREATE (haifa_avon_ferryprairie_C5)-[:postRel]->(haifa_avon_ferryprairie_5_P2:post {_id:2})
CREATE (haifa_avon_ferryprairie_C5)-[:postRel]->(haifa_avon_ferryprairie_5_P3:post {_id:3})
SET haifa_avon_ferryprairie_C5.post_count=3
with yafo_avon_pbotsfordforest, haifa_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, haifa_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_avon_psmithamcauseway, yafo_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_avon_pgoodwinramp, yafo_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_avon_pgoodwinramp, haifa_avon_psmithamcauseway, haifa_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp
MATCH (haifa_avon_pferryprairie)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_avon_ferryprairie_C3:circle {_id:3})
CREATE (haifa_avon_ferryprairie_C3)-[:postRel]->(haifa_avon_ferryprairie_3_P3:post {_id:3})
CREATE (haifa_avon_ferryprairie_C3)-[:postRel]->(haifa_avon_ferryprairie_3_P4:post {_id:4})
SET haifa_avon_ferryprairie_C3.post_count=4
with yafo_avon_pbotsfordforest, haifa_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, haifa_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_avon_psmithamcauseway, yafo_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_avon_pgoodwinramp, yafo_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_avon_pgoodwinramp, haifa_avon_psmithamcauseway, haifa_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp
MATCH (haifa_avon_pferryprairie)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_avon_ferryprairie_C2:circle {_id:2})
CREATE (haifa_avon_ferryprairie_C2)-[:postRel]->(haifa_avon_ferryprairie_2_P1:post {_id:1})
SET haifa_avon_ferryprairie_C2.post_count=1
with yafo_avon_pbotsfordforest, haifa_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, haifa_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_avon_psmithamcauseway, yafo_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_avon_pgoodwinramp, yafo_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_avon_pgoodwinramp, haifa_avon_psmithamcauseway, haifa_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp
MATCH (haifa_avon_pferryprairie)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_avon_ferryprairie_C1:circle {_id:1})
CREATE (haifa_avon_ferryprairie_C1)-[:postRel]->(haifa_avon_ferryprairie_1_P2:post {_id:2})
SET haifa_avon_ferryprairie_C1.post_count=2


WITH yafo_avon_pbotsfordforest, haifa_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, haifa_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_avon_psmithamcauseway, yafo_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_avon_pgoodwinramp, yafo_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_avon_pgoodwinramp, haifa_avon_psmithamcauseway, haifa_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp
MATCH (haifa_avon_pgoodwinramp)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_avon_goodwinramp_C1:circle {_id:1})
CREATE (haifa_avon_goodwinramp_C1)-[:postRel]->(haifa_avon_goodwinramp_1_P1:post {_id:1})
SET haifa_avon_goodwinramp_C1.post_count=1


WITH yafo_avon_pbotsfordforest, haifa_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, haifa_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_avon_psmithamcauseway, yafo_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_avon_pgoodwinramp, haifa_avon_psmithamcauseway, haifa_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp
CREATE (haifa_avon_psmithamcauseway)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_avon_smithamcauseway_C5:circle {_id:5})
CREATE (haifa_avon_psmithamcauseway)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_avon_smithamcauseway_C6:circle {_id:6})
CREATE (haifa_avon_psmithamcauseway)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_avon_smithamcauseway_C7:circle {_id:7})
SET haifa_avon_psmithamcauseway.circle_count=7
with yafo_avon_pbotsfordforest, haifa_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, haifa_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_avon_psmithamcauseway, yafo_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_avon_pgoodwinramp, haifa_avon_psmithamcauseway, haifa_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp
MATCH (haifa_avon_psmithamcauseway)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_avon_smithamcauseway_C1:circle {_id:1})
CREATE (haifa_avon_smithamcauseway_C1)-[:postRel]->(haifa_avon_smithamcauseway_1_P1:post {_id:1})
SET haifa_avon_smithamcauseway_C1.post_count=1


WITH yafo_avon_pbotsfordforest, haifa_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, haifa_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_avon_psmithamcauseway, yafo_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_avon_pgoodwinramp, haifa_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp
CREATE (haifa_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_bedfordshire_botsfordforest_C2:circle {_id:2})
CREATE (haifa_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_bedfordshire_botsfordforest_C3:circle {_id:3})
SET haifa_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest.circle_count=3


WITH yafo_avon_pbotsfordforest, haifa_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_avon_psmithamcauseway, yafo_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_avon_pgoodwinramp, haifa_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp
CREATE (haifa_bedfordshire_pferryprairie)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_bedfordshire_ferryprairie_C7:circle {_id:7})
CREATE (haifa_bedfordshire_pferryprairie)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_bedfordshire_ferryprairie_C8:circle {_id:8})
CREATE (haifa_bedfordshire_pferryprairie)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_bedfordshire_ferryprairie_C9:circle {_id:9})
CREATE (haifa_bedfordshire_pferryprairie)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_bedfordshire_ferryprairie_C10:circle {_id:10})
SET haifa_bedfordshire_pferryprairie.circle_count=10
with yafo_avon_pbotsfordforest, haifa_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_avon_psmithamcauseway, yafo_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_avon_pgoodwinramp, haifa_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp
MATCH (haifa_bedfordshire_pferryprairie)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_bedfordshire_ferryprairie_C5:circle {_id:5})
CREATE (haifa_bedfordshire_ferryprairie_C5)-[:postRel]->(haifa_bedfordshire_ferryprairie_5_P1:post {_id:1})
SET haifa_bedfordshire_ferryprairie_C5.post_count=1
with yafo_avon_pbotsfordforest, haifa_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_avon_psmithamcauseway, yafo_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_avon_pgoodwinramp, haifa_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp
MATCH (haifa_bedfordshire_pferryprairie)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_bedfordshire_ferryprairie_C2:circle {_id:2})
CREATE (haifa_bedfordshire_ferryprairie_C2)-[:postRel]->(haifa_bedfordshire_ferryprairie_2_P1:post {_id:1})
SET haifa_bedfordshire_ferryprairie_C2.post_count=1
with yafo_avon_pbotsfordforest, haifa_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_avon_psmithamcauseway, yafo_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_avon_pgoodwinramp, haifa_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp
MATCH (haifa_bedfordshire_pferryprairie)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_bedfordshire_ferryprairie_C6:circle {_id:6})
CREATE (haifa_bedfordshire_ferryprairie_C6)-[:postRel]->(haifa_bedfordshire_ferryprairie_6_P1:post {_id:1})
SET haifa_bedfordshire_ferryprairie_C6.post_count=1


WITH yafo_avon_pbotsfordforest, haifa_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_avon_psmithamcauseway, yafo_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_avon_pgoodwinramp, haifa_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_psmithamcauseway, haifa_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp
CREATE (haifa_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_bedfordshire_goodwinramp_C4:circle {_id:4})
SET haifa_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp.circle_count=4


WITH yafo_avon_pbotsfordforest, haifa_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_avon_psmithamcauseway, yafo_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_avon_pgoodwinramp, haifa_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_psmithamcauseway
MATCH (haifa_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_bedfordshire_smithamcauseway_C2:circle {_id:2})
CREATE (haifa_bedfordshire_smithamcauseway_C2)-[:postRel]->(haifa_bedfordshire_smithamcauseway_2_P1:post {_id:1})
SET haifa_bedfordshire_smithamcauseway_C2.post_count=1


WITH yafo_avon_pbotsfordforest, haifa_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_avon_psmithamcauseway, yafo_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_avon_pgoodwinramp, haifa_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_psmithamcauseway
CREATE (haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_berkshire_botsfordforest_C6:circle {_id:6})
SET haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest.circle_count=6
with yafo_avon_pbotsfordforest, haifa_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_avon_psmithamcauseway, yafo_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_avon_pgoodwinramp, haifa_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_psmithamcauseway
MATCH (haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_berkshire_botsfordforest_C1:circle {_id:1})
CREATE (haifa_berkshire_botsfordforest_C1)-[:postRel]->(haifa_berkshire_botsfordforest_1_P1:post {_id:1})
SET haifa_berkshire_botsfordforest_C1.post_count=1
with yafo_avon_pbotsfordforest, haifa_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_avon_psmithamcauseway, yafo_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_avon_pgoodwinramp, haifa_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_psmithamcauseway
MATCH (haifa_berkshire_pbotsfordforest)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_berkshire_botsfordforest_C2:circle {_id:2})
CREATE (haifa_berkshire_botsfordforest_C2)-[:postRel]->(haifa_berkshire_botsfordforest_2_P2:post {_id:2})
SET haifa_berkshire_botsfordforest_C2.post_count=2


WITH yafo_avon_pbotsfordforest, haifa_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_avon_psmithamcauseway, yafo_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_avon_pgoodwinramp, haifa_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_psmithamcauseway
CREATE (haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_berkshire_ferryprairie_C7:circle {_id:7})
SET haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie.circle_count=7
with yafo_avon_pbotsfordforest, haifa_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_avon_psmithamcauseway, yafo_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_avon_pgoodwinramp, haifa_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_psmithamcauseway
MATCH (haifa_berkshire_pferryprairie)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_berkshire_ferryprairie_C2:circle {_id:2})
CREATE (haifa_berkshire_ferryprairie_C2)-[:postRel]->(haifa_berkshire_ferryprairie_2_P1:post {_id:1})
SET haifa_berkshire_ferryprairie_C2.post_count=1


WITH yafo_avon_pbotsfordforest, haifa_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_bedfordshire_pferryprairie, haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_berkshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, haifa_berkshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_bedfordshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_avon_psmithamcauseway, yafo_berkshire_pferryprairie, haifa_cambridgeshire_pbotsfordforest, yafo_bedfordshire_psmithamcauseway, yafo_avon_pferryprairie, yafo_berkshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_avon_pgoodwinramp, haifa_cambridgeshire_pgoodwinramp, yafo_cambridgeshire_psmithamcauseway
CREATE (haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp)-[:circleRel]->(haifa_berkshire_goodwinramp_C3:circle {_id:3})
SET haifa_berkshire_pgoodwinramp.circle_count=3
```

I have one constraint:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (country:country) ASSERT country._id IS UNIQUE
```

Answer (score 0):

I just take the first lines of your queries :

```
MERGE (pisrael:country {_id:'israel'})
MERGE (pisrael)-[:Has]->(pyafo:city {_id:'yafo'})
```

And you said you only hvae a constraint on `:country(_id)`

So for the first line it's perfect, it will be fast !

But `MERGE (pisrael)-[:Has]->(pyafo:city {_id:'yafo'})` can be slow ...

**Why ?**

You are asking the database to find the node `(:city {_id:'yafo'})`, and then to create the relationship if it not exists.
But what if your have 1 billion of `city` node ? ... this part will be slow because Neo4j will have to do a full scan of `city` node. 
To avoid that you should create an index or a constraint.

You can apply this advice for the rest of your query, so at the end you should create those indexes :

```
CREATE INDEX :city(_id);
CREATE INDEX :street(_id);
CREATE INDEX :region(_id);
```

Comment: This isn't quite accurate. Since the MERGE only has a single bound node `pisrael`, it will expand from that node and see if the pyafo :city node with the provided _id exists. It will not attempt to match to `(pyafo:city {_id:'yafo'})` first, as that would actually be incorrect behavior. The MERGE in this case isn't dependent upon the number of :city nodes, nor on an index on :city(_id). See [How MERGE works](https://community.neo4j.com/t/understanding-how-merge-works/318) for more details

Comment: Though it should be noted, this will result in the creation of a new :city node with _id:'yafo', even if there is already a node like that in the graph. If the intent is to have only one :city node with a given _id, then you should MERGE that node separately, before you MERGE the relationship between them. And for this case, what logisima suggests is correct, you want an index here to make the MERGE on the :city node quick.

Comment: I can't add constraints on label street and region because it is unique only per pattern, and what I want to do here is writing data to database not read it so index and constraint will slow down the transaction. When I perform the query the second time it takes 80ms so I think it is something related with neo4j internal cache, what I basically do is merging throw the graph and get all endpoints that will be linked with new created nodes, so I used `with` that has all the endpoints to keep reference of them while linking them with new nodes.

Comment: I also noticed that decreasing the elements in `with` statement slightly helped but not that much.